# Determining order of an element

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n$ be the smallest integer such that $a^n \equiv -1 \ (mod \  m)$

Show that $ord_m(a) = 2n$

My proof says that, if there exists an integer $k$, with $k<2n$ then $a^{2n} \equiv a^k \ (mod \ m)$

Now we have $a^{2n-k} \equiv 1 \ (mod \ m)$ From this we can see that either $k$ or $2n-k$ is less than $n$. Say $r$ is whichever is less than $n$.

Therefore $a^{n-r} \equiv -1 \ (mod \ m)$ contradicting the assumptions that $n$ is the lowest such integer.

Is my proof correct and is there a easier way to prove the statement?

Comment: The general idea is right, and there really is no shorter way. There are gaps you could have easily filled in. Note that we must have $m\gt 2$.

Answer (score 0):

**A variant:**

As $a^{2n}=1$, the order of $a$ is a divisor of $2n$, which cannot be a divisor of $n$. Hence it is $2d$ for some (strict) divisor of $n$. Then we have $a^{n-2d}=-1$.

However, as $d$ is a strict divisor of $n$ and $2d$ is not, we have $0 <n-2d <n$, contradicting the minimality of $n$.